# mysql MODIFY BIGINT выдает ошибку - ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql

Ребята что я делаю не так ?

С колонками с типом VARCHAR все нормально, а BIGINT проблема.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY lastupdate BIGINT(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci' at
>   line 1

Ошибку выдаёт на BIGINT,tinyint,longblob типах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У чисел и блобов (т.е. бинарных данных) по очевидным причинам нет кодировки. Кодировка и кодировка сравнения - свойства текстовых данных.

Comment: У меня utf8_unicode_ci  стоит по всей базе,Прочитал что он медленнее чем utf8_general_ci. Так как мне быть,Не трогать их  ?

Comment: Если вы не понимаете, что у нетекстовых данных в принципе не может быть кодировки - лучше вообще ничего не делайте с кодировками. И лишний раз проверьте наличие и возможность восстановить данные из бекапа.